# C# SMTPClient Timeout Question

Tags: c#, smtpclient

I was wondering, do you really have to increase the timeout of a send operation manually for sending large attachments. I read the Microsoft documentation located [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.timeout.aspx) and it says the timeout length is 100 seconds. Instead of working with timeout, I was wondering if its possible to rather just tell it to continue going until either an error is found or the mail message is sent successfully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The very page you link already gives the answer: use the SendAsync method. From the [SendAsync documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h.aspx):

> To receive notification when the e-mail has been sent or the operation has been canceled, add an event handler to the SendCompleted event.

The SendCompleted event requires a [SendCompletedEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h.aspx) delegate, which in turn receives a [AsyncCompletedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h.aspx) instance, which can be used to find out whether sending succeeded.

Comment: If the async method fails is there a callback?