# what is the cause of SMTP.MAIL: the Operation has timed out?

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtpclient

I am creating an intranet web-based application that will send notifications to its users depending on the Admin's choice.

**I developed the Mailing page correctly and it work fine with 15 or 20 users. Now, I have more than 200 users, so when I run this page I got the following error and I don't know why:**

> Exception Details: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The operation has
>   timed out.

My Code-Behind (C#):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendEmailTOAllUser();
    }


    protected void SendEmail(string toAddresses, string fromAddress, string MailSubject, string MessageBody, bool isBodyHtml)
    {
        SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("MAIL.companyDomainName.com");
        try
        {
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.From = new MailAddress("pssp@companyDomainName.com", "PMOD Safety Services Portal (PSSP)");

            // In case the mail system doesn't like no to recipients. This could be removed
            //msg.To.Add("pssp@companyDomainName.com");

            msg.Bcc.Add(toAddresses);
            msg.Subject = MailSubject;
            msg.Body = MessageBody;
            msg.IsBodyHtml = isBodyHtml;
            //Response.Write(msg);
            sc.Send(msg);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }

    protected void SendEmailTOAllUser()

    {
        string connString = "Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=psspEmail;Integrated Security=True";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            var sbEmailAddresses = new System.Text.StringBuilder(1000);
            string quizid = "";

            // Open DB connection.
            conn.Open();

            string cmdText = "SELECT MIN (QuizID) As mQuizID FROM dbo.QUIZ WHERE IsSent <> 1";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
            {
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader != null)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        // There is only 1 column, so just retrieve it using the ordinal position
                        quizid = reader["mQuizID"].ToString();

                    }
                }
                reader.Close();
            }

            string cmdText2 = "SELECT Username FROM dbo.employee";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText2, conn))
            {
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader != null)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        var sName = reader.GetString(0);
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sName))
                        {
                            if (sbEmailAddresses.Length != 0)
                            {
                                sbEmailAddresses.Append(",");
                            }
                            // Just use the ordinal position for the user name since there is only 1 column
                            sbEmailAddresses.Append(sName).Append("@companyDomainName.com");
                        }
                    }
                }
                reader.Close();
            }

            string cmdText3 = "UPDATE dbo.Quiz SET IsSent = 1 WHERE QuizId = @QuizID";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText3, conn))
            {
                // Add the parameter to the command
                var oParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@QuizID", SqlDbType.Int);
                // Get a local copy of the email addresses
                var sEMailAddresses = sbEmailAddresses.ToString();


                    string link = "<a href='http://pmv/pssp/StartQuiz.aspx?testid=" + quizid + "'> Click here to participate </a>";
                    string body = @"Good day, <br /><br />
                                <b> Please participate in the new short safety quiz </b>"
                                        + link +
                                        @"<br /><br />
                            Also, give yourself a chance to gain more safety culture by reading the PMOD Newsletter.
                            <br /> <br /><br /> <br />
                            This email was generated using the <a href='http://pmv/pssp/Default.aspx'>PMOD Safety Services Portal (PSSP) </a>. 
                            Please do not reply to this email.
                            ";

                    SendEmail(sEMailAddresses, "", "Notification of New Weekly Safety Quiz", body, true);

                    // Update the parameter for the current quiz
                    oParameter.Value = quizid;
                    // And execute the command
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

**Any help please?**

Comment: How many users will use this code to send email at the same time ?

Comment: I am the only one will use this code to send email. But the email will be sent to 386 users.

Comment: I mean how many mail will be sent using this code at the same time ?

Comment: possible duplicate :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474641/c-sharp-smtpclient-timeout-question

Comment: It is not duplicate. And the same email will be sent to 386 users but the users will be in BCC so I think the email will be just sent as once.

Comment: Test sending your email using SendAsync (like the answer to the above post) and see if you are getting time out exception again

Comment: Ok could you please tell me what I should modify in my code? Because I working under a very tight schedule.

Answer (score 2):

1. make sure your SMTP server is online, as my test "telnet MAIL.Aramco.com 25", it displays the server is unavailable.
2. As your code, you are using SMTP server but no authentication, does it support anonymously access?

Comment: Since he says that's working with 15-20 users without problem there's a possibility that it's a concurrency issue.

Comment: As  @Beatles1692 said, I already be able to send an emails to 15 and 30 users. My problem now is with 386 users.

Answer (score 2):

add **sc.timeout=600000(10min)** 
in send email method.

if email send requires more time to complete the it allows you

Comment: if you add sc.timeout=600000;  this parameter is allow to complete current request first and then execute next. i.e- if email having large size, then more time required to send that email. so smtpClient do not stop operation till email is send.

Comment: If you add this information to your answer - the answer will be much better. Remember that you can always edit your own questions and answers.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a concurrency issue as it seems maybe using SendAsync can help to solve your probelm as it discussed in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474641/c-sharp-smtpclient-timeout-question)

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h.aspx)'s an example in MSDN that might help. You should replace the Send method with SendAsync as this code shows.

Comment: Could you please tell me what I should change in my code? Because I am running out of time.

Comment: Replace Send with SendAsync. If you want you can send a user state to track a particular email in CompletedEvent

Comment: when I replaced it to sc.SendAsync(msg); I got the following error: No overload for method 'SendAsync' takes 1 arguments.

Comment: you should send a userstate to SendAsync method. send null if you don't want to send some specific data

Comment: Even when I put it as a null, I got the following error: Asynchronous operations are not allowed in this context. Page starting an asynchronous operation has to have the Async attribute set to true and an asynchronous operation can only be started on a page prior to PreRenderComplete event.

Comment: Then you should set the async attribute of your page to true.like this (<%@ Page Async="true" ... %>) here's an article that might help in this regard : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx